How to access to historical FDA clearances result of each owner/operator number
I was hoping to seek another guidance on how to find all the cleared devices of an identified owneroperator number.

For example, Vysioneer Inc. (Owner/Operator number: 10082889) has cleared three devices: K213628, K212116, and K203235.
However, the Owner/Operator number 10082889 only returns two devices when using the following link (https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfrl/rl.cfm).
I was able to confirm that Vysioneer Inc. has cleared three devices by downloading the entire 510(k) list and identifying its devices by searching the company’s name.


Thank you for your question. We would like to know whether you're specifically looking for hosting data on accessdata or openFDA. If its not openFDA, then unfortunately we won't be able to help with this.
Thank you.
Note: I'm a member of openFDA team.
